# Flink timeout using KeyedCoProcessFunction and order of reading for FlinkKafkaConsumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using the `KeyedCoProcessFunction` class in Flink DataStream APIs to implement a timeout like use case. The scenario is as follows: I have an input kafka topic and an output Kafka topic,  a service reads from the input topic processes it (for variable amount of time) and then publishes the response in the output kafka topic.

Now to implement the timeout (must be using Flink datastream APIs), I have a `FlinkKafkaConsumer` that reads from the kafka input topic, and another `FlinkKafkaConsumer` that reads from the kafka output topic. I am connecting the two streams, and  using the `processElement1` I am registering a timer and waiting either that the `onTimer` method be fired (a timeout is declared), or the `processElement2` is fired before and hence I delete the timer and do not declare a timeout.

While testing on large scale events, I am seeing `NULLPTREXCEPTION` and I suspect that `processElement2` is fired before `ProcessElement1`, in the situation described above can the scenario of reading an element from the output topic  happen before reading from the input topic due to any reason  (knowing that the time taken to process the element by the service might take seconds)  and in such case what is the best case to implement the timeout functionality as described above **strictly using the Flink DataStream APIs**, Any hint please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's no guarantee that Flink will call the `processElement1` method before `processElement2`. It's likely, but not certain. Or in other words, it probably won't always be the case.

This is exactly the same scenario as you will find in the LongRideAlerts exercise in the Flink Training -- https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/long-ride-alerts -- so you might emulate the [solution](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/long-ride-alerts/src/solution/java/org/apache/flink/training/solutions/longrides/LongRidesSolution.java) used there. The logic is this:

- whichever event (for a given key) arrives first, from either stream, store it
- if it is the input event (from topic1) that arrives first, set a timer
- if it is the output event (from topic2) that arrives second, before the timer fires, delete the timer
- whichever event (for a given key) arrives second, from either stream, clear the state (that is shared by the two streams)
- whenever the timer fires, use the input event saved from topic1 in keyed state to create a report and clear the state

This solution does leak state whenever an input event from topic1 is missing. See the [discussion](https://github.com/apache/flink-training/blob/master/long-ride-alerts/DISCUSSION.md) accompanying the training exercise for how to deal with that, if it matters (short version: use [state TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl)).

Comment: Even If processElement1  comes way before processElement2 there is no guarantee on the order of calling, why is that? is there any way of forcing Flink to process first whichever element arrives first?

Comment: It is possible to force Flink to control the order in which a two-input stream operator reads from its inputs, but if you use that interface deadlocks are possible, and checkpointing may not work. In general it's better to cope with not knowing when the events will come. And even if you did use that mechanism, you would still not have a 100% guarantee.

Comment: between were routing me to this https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_scala/process/ExpiringStateSolution.scala

Comment: Thank you sir, the example you mentionned in your first reply deals with one input stream 'rides', while in my case i have two different input streams (two different kafka consumers), so is it possible to route two different streams of the same type to the same Flink process function? and how about read ordering in such case is it first come first served?

Comment: Yes, you can route two streams of the same type to a CoProcessFunction, and you shouldn't expect to have any influence over when the operator will read from one input vs the other.

Comment: The ExpiringState exercise you found, or https://github.com/apache/flink-training/tree/master/rides-and-fares, these are examples that involve two separate input streams, but they don't have quite the same "match two events before a timeout" requirement as in the first example I shared.

Comment: when i have two different input streams keyed by the same id, and read from two different sources (say two different kafka topics, with first stream is published/read from topic1, and after few seconds second stream is published/read from topic2), how would i implement a timeout functionality (if have not received an event from stream 2)...
it looks like impossible to implement using flink datastream APIs if i have no control over which element will be read first by a two inout stream operator? thank you so much I am sorry but i still do not get solution point.

Comment: It works just as I've outlined in my answer above (which I've edit a bit to try to clarify things). The reason this works is because the state and timers are per-key, and are shared between the two input streams. It makes no difference to the processing logic that the events are coming from two different streams. In the LongRides example there are START and END events in the same stream, but they could just as well be coming from different streams.

Comment: Perhaps I have completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. So  I can conclude that if an event is available now to Flink and if  another event will be available 1 minute later (same key), as a result of connecting the two streams,  Flink does not provide any guarantee that the event available now will be processed before the event available 1 minute later? is that accurate? and if that is the case why it would do that maybe is counter intuitive.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, if it is indeed one minute later then of course it is extremely unlikely. But the issue is that various parts of the pipeline are sometimes running in different threads, and sometimes in different processes, and sometimes on different machines. So a lot of things outside of Flink can have an effect.